# ui-icon not showing using jquery ui css

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am trying co create list using jQuery ui classes.

**Problem**  is

```
<span class="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>
```

is not appearing .. It should appear to right end.

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/MNe4s/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ui-splitselect ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget ui-widget-content" >
<div class="ui-widget-content list-available">
    <ul class="list available" style=" ">
        <li class="ui-state-default">
            <div class='handle ui-widget-header'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s'></span></div>
              Epania    
              <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">
                    <span class="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>
                </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-splitselect{font-size:.8em}
.ui-splitselect ul{-moz-user-select:none}
.ui-splitselect div.list-selected{float:left;border:none;margin:0;padding:0}
.ui-splitselect div.list-available{float:left;border-top:none;border-bottom:none;border-right:none;margin:0;padding:0}
.ui-splitselect ul.list{position:relative;overflow:auto;overflow-x:hidden;list-style:none;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0}
.ui-splitselect li{cursor:default;line-height:20px;height:20px;font-size:11px;list-style:none;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;margin:1px;padding:0}
.ui-splitselect li a{color:#999;text-decoration:none;display:block;float:left;cursor:pointer;padding:0}
.ui-splitselect li .handle{float:left;height:20px;border-top:0;border-bottom:0;margin:0 10px 0 5px;padding:2px 5px}
.ui-splitselect li.ui-state-focus .handle{border:inherit;border-top:0;border-bottom:0}
.ui-splitselect .ui-widget-header{border:none;font-size:11px;margin-bottom:1px}
```

Comment: are you talking about the plus icon? it shows in your JSFiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tTdXa/

Comment: The plus icon appears for me, I assume you want it to float to the right?

Comment: @Adam does not work in Firefox

Comment: Oh I hate jquery ui <3 bootstrap

Comment: yes, it does not work in firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi your problem is in the HTML, set the text content in `<span>` tag and give to it the property `float:left`. I've set a class named `text` for this span and give the icon `float` to the right.

View this demo **http://jsfiddle.net/MNe4s/13/** and ask any question.

Comment: :see Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/MNe4s/14/ .Now when I Change the theme from base to any other , icons are not visible.I was assuming since icons are placed inside ui-widget-header , they will inherit span color from that.How to fix this ?

Comment: I see the icons his color is always that gray they are an sprite image to change the icons color you have to change the backgroun-image in css